# system warning sound on text box keyup event C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I Have a login form. In the `KeyUp` event of `txtUserName` textbox have this,

```
private void txtUserID_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return))
        {
            //Next control when Press Enter key
            SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, true, true);
        }
    }
```

But everytime i press `Enter Key`,Focus goes to next contol and produce a System warning sound.

How can i avoid this or What is the wrong with this?

Comment: what you ware tried to achieve? whats wrong thing that you are facing?

Comment: add 
```e.SuppressKeyPress = true;```
after SelectNextControl...

Comment: When user press `Enter key` after input their username, focus goes to next `txtPassword`Control , This works fine. but along with System sound.I want prevent that System sound.

Comment: @meganaut  Still the same.

Comment: Using `KeyPress` event you can check `if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)` then select next control `SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, true, true);` and then set `e.Handled = true;`

Comment: @RezaAghaei ,Woks fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you press enter key, along side your code, the default event fires too.
Add `e.Handled = true`, to your method:

```
private void txtUserID_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return))
        {
            //Next control when Press Enter key
            SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, true, true);
            e.Handled = true
        }
    }
```

This tells that event is handled.

Comment: Thanks, Fixed with @RezaAghaei advice.